# Spring autowire multiple implementation of Interface

Tags: java, spring, annotations

```
interface A{
 void some();
}

@Component
class B implements A{
 @override
 some(){
 }
}

@Component
class C implements A{
@override
 some(){
 }
}

Class D {
@Autowired
List<A> somes;//will it have the instances of both
}
```

I am working on a project where we have multiple classes implement the same interface.
How do I get the list in class D to contain beans for both class B and class C?

Answer (score 8):

Actually you will get a resolving bean conflicts **exception**,

There are a various solutions for that :

1. Making one of the beans optional by using **@Primary** annotation.

```java
@Component
@Primary
class B implements A{

    @override
    some(){
    }

}

@Component
class C implements A{

    @override
    some(){
    }

}

Class D {

    @Autowired
    List<A> somes;//B will be injected because it primary

}
```

3. Or Using **@Qualifier** or **@Resource** annotation.
   scenarios.

```java
@Component("beanB")
class B implements A{

    @override
    some(){
    }

}

@Component("beanC")
class C implements A{

    @override
    some(){
    }

}

Class D {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("beanB")
    List<A> somes;//B will be injected because of @Qualifier

}
```